# Any way to use variable in PHP namespace?

Tags: php, frameworks, namespaces

Got a framework with thousands of files, all starting with hard-coded

"namespace SOMETHING"

Is there a way to replace the SOMETHING with a variable?

"namespace $SOMETHING"

Comment: yes of course there's, AWK/SED, "refactor" tool in better IDEs, etc., etc.  But is there a way to do this inside PHP, or must namespaces presently be hard-coded in every file?  Would love to be able to setup a config and be able to change the framework namespace in one place.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Refactor Namespaces in PHP, is it possible to do this with a variable or define?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543351/refactor-namespaces-in-php-is-it-possible-to-do-this-with-a-variable-or-define)

Comment: of course it's a dup.  that q got beat up for no good reason.  please focus on the q and a.

Comment: I think you should ask your question is your question come with good reason?

Comment: I'd still want to know *why*. Because you want to use "variable namespaces"? That's something I'd really argue against. Or just for refactoring? Then you'd still have to edit every single file to include a variable or constant definition...

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use *variable namespaces*, for several reasons:

- "Namespaces are declared using the namespace keyword. A file containing a namespace must declare the namespace at the top of the file before any other code." http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.definition.php

  So, you can't even declare or import a variable definition before declaring the namespace.
- It's a syntax error:

  ```
  namespace $bar;
  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE,
  expecting T_STRING or T_NS_SEPARATOR or '{'
  ```
- "variable namespaces" sounds like a Really Bad Idea and I cannot come up with a use case that's not bordering on abuse
- you couldn't use constants (as suggested in your previous question), since the syntax would be indistinguishable to a normal namespace declaration